# Can Netty 4.1 talk with Netty 3.6?

Tags: netty

I have 2 versions of a messaging project, newer version of the project uses Netty 4.1.19.Final, the old version uses Netty 3.6.10.Final.

Some customers have problems to send/receive messages between the 2 versions of the project, which after debugging, points to that it might be the reason that Netty 4.1.19.Final failed to get the response from Netty 3.6.10.Final after it sends the TCP packets.

So can Netty 4.1 talk with netty 3.6? Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 5):

Yes there should be no problem using different versions of netty as both just use "sockets" to communicate via the network. The only problem I can think if would be if the actual encoder / decoder implementation would be different in both versions and one of these would be buggy.

Answer (score 0):

Netty is built on the TCP protocol so whichever version you use will not have any impact on your project. The one difference between 3.x and 4.x is that netty 4.x simplified the handler mechanism, from upstream  downstream to inbound outbound, and provides memo pool to optimize GC problem.